# Change document.getElementById to a Ref

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm trying to replace `document.getElementById('firstnaem').focus();` to use a React ref, but I can't get it to work. I've heard accessing the DOM directly in React is bad practice, but I can't get it to work without `document.getElementById`.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, forwardRef } from 'react';
import Overlay from 'react-bootstrap/Overlay';
import FloatingLabelInput from 'react-floating-label-input';
function RegisterClipboard(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const handleFirstNameChange = (event) => {
        setUser({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            firstName: event.target.value,
            lastName: user.lastName
        });
    };
    const handleFirstNameOnBlur = (event) => {
        if (user.firstname === undefined){

        }else if (regExName.test(user.firstName) === false) {
            firstNameValid(false);
            setTarget(event.target);
        } else if (regExName.test(user.firstName) === true) {
            firstNameValid(true);
        }
    }
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
       //Empty the fields
        setUser({
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        });
        //Doesn't work: document.querySelector("input").focus();
        //Works, but I don't think you're supposed to access the DOM directly in react: document.getElementById("firstName").focus();
        //Didn't work with focus or blur: setTimeout(function(){inputRef.current.focus();}, 3000);
        //Throws an error inputRef.current is not a function: inputRef.current.focus();
        //Doesn't work: () => textInput.current.focus()
        console.log(user.firstname);
    }
    const firstNameOverlay =
        <Overlay
            show={!firstName}
            target={target}
            placement="bottom"
            container={ref.current}
        >
            <div className="warningTextOnUserInput">
                For your first name, please enter at least two characters with letters, hyphens, and apostrophes.
            </div>
        </Overlay>;
    return (
        <div className={props.className} id="registerClipboard">
            <Form className="form">
                <ClipboardClip />
                <div className="centeredPaper">
                    <div ref={ref}>
                        {firstNameOverlay}
                        <Form.Group controlId="firstName" >
                            <FloatingLabelInput
                                id="firstName"
                                label="First Name"
                                type="firstName"
                                name="firstName"
                                ref= {inputRef} 
                                value={user.firstName}
                                onChange={handleFirstNameChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </div>
                    <div ref={ref}>
                        <Button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>
                            Register
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
    }
export default RegisterClipboard;
```

Does anyone know how to get `refs` to work in this context? I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: where you use `handleClick`?

Comment: ref current object is depending on FloatingLabelInput

Comment: @Viet, I'm sorry. I was trying to take out some complexity from the code, but I probably went to far. I readded the handleClick and the overlays. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this part. `react-floating-label-input` passes down `refs` plural to the input `ref`. I missed the `s` at the end, but once I added the `s` , it worked just as expected. The documentation says it at the bottom of the page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-floating-label-input. I just didn't realize I needed a different attribute to use this dependency. I'm guessing this is a custom attribute, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the validation before accessing Ref, otherwise use the chaining operator like `inputRef?.current`.

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not quite sure I understand checking "the validation before accessing the ref".  I couldn't get `inputRef?.current` to work either.